# CellObject[Number] to its content

Tags: front-end, notebooks, expression-manipulation, cells

As in the following sreenshots, roughly speaking, `Out[43]` is `CellObject[97601]`.

[image]
[image]

I want to set `var1` = the content of `CellObject[97601]`. So that

```
In[44] var1=SomeFunction[CellObject[97601]]
Out[44] 123456789101112
```

But I do not know how to get the content of `CellObject[97601]`.
How can I construct `SomeFunction`?

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

Thank you, Michael E2, it works well :

[image]

Copy As Cell Object : CellObject[99121]

[image]

Similar method does not work for Text Cell. But the solution is simpler :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NotebookRead` gives the cell expression (see the first example in the docs for `CellObject`); `ToExpression` can convert the boxes:

```
NotebookRead[cobj]
(*
Cell[BoxData[
  RowBox[{"Integrate", "[", 
    RowBox[{RowBox[{"1", "/", SqrtBox[RowBox[{"1", "-", "x"}]]}], ",",
       "x"}], "]"}]], "Input", CellChangeTimes -> {3.86329*10^9}]
*)

ToExpression[
 First@First@NotebookRead[cobj], StandardForm, HoldComplete]

(*  HoldComplete[\[Integral]1/Sqrt[1 - x] \[DifferentialD]x]  *)
```

The cell read was an input cell containing `Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - x], x]`, but `ToExpression` does convert boxes to `InputForm`.

Comment: Thank you, `NotebookRead` is important.